# Setting font for title bar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Can we set a font, size for the text on the title bar in tkinter?
I think it cannot be done as it is not even required. But if there is a way then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we set a font, size for the text on the title bar in tkinter?

No, tkinter doesn't provide a way to do that.

Comment: Qt does or not?

Comment: @AjaySinghRana: I have no idea. I've never used Qt.